# How to replace "Enter quantity" text for Production variation?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm working on Drupal commerce kickstart.

On Product variation, I need to change the text **Enter quantity** to **Enter your quantities** and change **Add to Cart** to **Buy Now**.

I tried with form alter it works to change **Add to Cart** to **Buy Now** but its not working for **Enter quantity** to **Enter your quantities**.

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. Because this text is hardcoded and there is no configuration for updating the text.

**Ways to change the text**

- Use [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.
- Do a form_alter and change the text from **Add to Cart** to **Buy Now**

**Form Alter for Enter quantity**

```
function module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form') {
    $form['quantity']['#title'] = t('Enter your Quantities');
  }
}
```

Hope this code helps.

Answer (score 0):

This string is being set by a form_alter in the commerce_kickstart_product_ui.module.
You can use the module string_overrides: https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides to change the string, or
You can use your own form alter code in a custom module but you may have to use the weight module https://drupal.org/project/modules_weight so that your module executes it's code after te commerce module.